# ngDialog default settings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ngDialog directive in Angularjs. Currently, I set the closeByEscape: false wherever I am calling the ngDialog.open() method. Is there any way to set this setting globally so that I no need to set this setting everytime.

Comment: Did you check [setting default settings](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#setdefaultsoptions) ?

Comment: Thanks. I did not check it early.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out the docs [here](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#user-content-setdefaultsoptions).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDialog']);
app.config(['ngDialogProvider', function (ngDialogProvider) {
    ngDialogProvider.setDefaults({
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        plain: true,
        showClose: true,
        closeByDocument: true,
        closeByEscape: true
    });
}]);
```